# XMLHttpRequest cannot load. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: ajax, json, apache, cors, javascript-faq

Добрый день. Есть задача: используя REST API [сервиса доставки](https://pickpoint.ru/), описанный [здесь](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wwmugw38nr5hjt5/2015.04.09_%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%20API%20last.doc?dl=0), осуществить запрос стоимости доставки. Для этого нужно открыть сессию(Login), выполнить запрос, а после закрыть(Logout). Не получается открыть сессию.

Написал js-код для осуществления кросс-доменного запроса и возврата результата.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'http://e-solution.pickpoint.ru/apitest/login',
            crossDomain: true,
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                Login: 'apitest',
                Password: 'apitest'
            },
            xhrFields: {
                withCredentials: false
            },
            success: function (status) {
                console.log(status);
            },
            error: function (xhr, status) {
                console.log(xhr);
                console.log(status);
            }
        });
    });
```

**Получаю ошибку в консоли:**

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://e-solution.pickpoint.ru/apitest/login. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin '<Адрес моего сайта>' is therefore not allowed access.
```

**Вывод:**

```
Object {readyState: 0, responseJSON: undefined, status: 0, statusText: "error"}
```

**На основе гугления добавил соответствующие заголовки. Фрагмент файла .htaccess:**

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header add X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
    Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
    Header add Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
    Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
    Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
</IfModule>
```

Так же добавил в начало файла строку:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

Но по-прежнему не получается осуществить запрос. Что делать?

Comment: .htaccess тут же `e-solution.pickpoint.ru` лежит?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Политика безопасности браузеров запрещает выполнение кроссдоменных AJAX запросов. Чтобы это обойти, как было замечено выше нужно добавить заголовок Access-Control-Allow-Origin, но возвращать его должен домен к которому вы обращаетесь. Я так понимаю доступа для изменения настроек у вас к нему нет.

Обходится это следующим образом, вы делаете запрос к серверному скрипту, расположенному на вашем сайте, который перенаправляет запрос на нужный сайт.

Comment: Только перенаправляет? Или серверный скрипт должен получить данные и вернуть их?

Comment: @abg это зависит от логики вашего приложения.

Answer (score 1):

Искал тоже самое и наткнулся на ответ SiZE. Всё верно кроме как сделать простенький curl запрос на получение контента, и отдать его в скрипт js больше возможности нет.

```
 /**
 * Get a web file (HTML, XHTML, XML, image, etc.) from a URL.  Return an
 * array containing the HTTP server response header fields and content.
 */
function get_web_page( $url )
{
    $user_agent='Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:8.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/8.0';

    $options = array(

        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST  =>"GET",        //set request type post or get
        CURLOPT_POST           =>false,        //set to GET
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => $user_agent, //set user agent
        CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE     =>"cookie.txt", //set cookie file
        CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR      =>"cookie.txt", //set cookie jar
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,     // return web page
        CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,    // don't return headers
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,     // follow redirects
        CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "",       // handle all encodings
        CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,     // set referer on redirect
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,      // timeout on connect
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 120,      // timeout on response
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,       // stop after 10 redirects
    );

    $ch      = curl_init( $url );
    curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );
    $content = curl_exec( $ch );
    $err     = curl_errno( $ch );
    $errmsg  = curl_error( $ch );
    $header  = curl_getinfo( $ch );
    curl_close( $ch );

    $header['errno']   = $err;
    $header['errmsg']  = $errmsg;
    $header['content'] = $content;
    return $header;
}
```

**Пример**

```
//Read a web page and check for errors:
$result = get_web_page( $url );

if ( $result['errno'] != 0 )
... error: bad url, timeout, redirect loop ...

if ( $result['http_code'] != 200 )
... error: no page, no permissions, no service ...

$page = $result['content'];
```

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14953910/5027993)