# XMLHttpRequest cannot load

Tags: jquery, ajax

Есть следующий код:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$.ajax({
    url: "http://vm1.culture.ru/abramtsevo/catalog/ajax.php",
    data: {
        YEAR_SEARCH_LEFT: "-99",
        YEAR_SEARCH_RIGHT: "1999",
        TEGS: "Предметы быта"
    },
    type: 'POST',
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function() {
        alert("Success");
    },
});
</script>
```

Как все-таки можно избежать злосчастной ошибки "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access"?

И вопрос, чтобы не было полного дублирования: каким образом механизм https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/ (если добавить перед ссылкой в "url", чтобы было "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://vm1.culture.ru/abramtsevo/catalog/ajax.php", все работает) это все обходит?

Этот же проект на github: https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere

Comment: Никак, [same-origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) не позволит.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [XMLHttpRequest cannot load. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/435319/xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-o)

Comment: Дубляж : http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/435319/xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-o. Внимательно ищите поиском. А вообще - Сергей все верно ответил - почитайте про кроссдоменные запросы.

Comment: Обновил вопрос.

Comment: `каким образом механизм https://corsanywhere.herokuapp.com/  ... это все обходит?` .......дык вы с клиента шлёте, а тот проект на сервере колдует...... разница налицо.... на сервере каких чудес только сотворить нельзя

Comment: `cors-anywhere` - прокси сервер, который пробрасывает запросы нужным серверам и добавляет к ответам заголовок `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`. Если у вас есть свой сервер, вы можете легко его там поднять. Кстати, объяснение этого есть в в ответе на тот вопрос, который вы дублируете.

Comment: Спасибо, теперь понятнее!