# Помогите пожалуйста разобраться с тонкостями JS

Tags: javascript

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться с тонкостями JS

```js
var npage;
fetch('https://news.yandex.ru/yandsearch?rpt=nnews2&grhow=clutop&text=security')
    .then(function(response) {
         return response.text();
    }).then(function(content) {
        npage = content;
    });
```

Если данный код размещен на произвольном веб-ресурсе (например, на https://testsite.com/ ). Какие данные будут в переменной npage? А что будет в переменной npage, если выполнить этот код на https://news.yandex.ru? Из-за чего возникла разница?

Comment: С чего вы взяли, что будет разница? Возможно вы получите ошибку «cross -origin»

Comment: Ошибка в консоли "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" однозначно говорит вам о проблеме.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [XMLHttpRequest cannot load. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/435319/xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-o)