# Angular проблема с CORS

Tags: angular2, typescript, cors

Пытаюсь на одном сайте отправить запрос к другому сайту (имеется доступ) через функцию:

```
private GetHouseSeries(suggestion) {

    const httpOptions = {

      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      })

    };

    this.http.post(this.CONFIG.urlSkachayOkno+"/.ajax/getHouseByAddress.php?address=" + suggestion.value, httpOptions).subscribe(data => {

      let successButton = document.getElementsByClassName("address-search-form__submit-button") as HTMLCollectionOf<HTMLElement>;
      if (successButton.length != 0) {
        successButton[0].classList.add('visible');
        successButton[0].setAttribute("data_href", (data as any).SERIES_URL);
      }

    });
  }
```

В консоли ошибки: 
[image: Ошибка CORS]
Хотя в network:
[image: Network code 200]

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [XMLHttpRequest cannot load. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/435319/xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-o)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В настройках сервера,к которому делал запрос,добавил заголовок Access-Control-Allow-Origin.