# Не могу отправить POST Запрос на server с помощь Angular 7

Tags: angular7

Не могу отправить POST Запрос на server с помощь Angular 7 выдает следущую ощибку :"Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://unfaithfuldate.com/user/api. (Reason: missing token 'authorization' in CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' from CORS preflight channel)."
GET запрос работает а POST не работает

Comment: вопросов с таким топиком на SO наверное уже пруд пруди :)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/435333/303477